# Expo launch Camera Async Android not working

Tags: react-native, expo

the following codes work with expo but not when I get build. Help me please.

```
_pickImage2 = async () => {
      await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1
      });

      if (!result.cancelled) {
        var cr = this.state.count;
        this.setState({ ["image"+cr]: result.uri });
        var cn = this.state.count + 1;
        this.setState({ count:cn });
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add permissions to app.json and rebuild the apk

```
 "android": {
      "package": "com.company.someapp",

      "permissions": [

        "CAMERA",
         "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: can you supply details of error? i edited the answer with full permissions details in my app

Comment: you usually need to add permissions to app.json file to work on the release/production/standalone apk.